# How to declare the type for local variables using PHPDoc notation?

Tags: php, cakephp, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt, cakephp-2.2

I use Zend Studio to develop in PHP with CakePHP, and one of the problems with CakePHP is that the views all reference undeclared local variables.

So for example, in the controller you would

`$this->set('job',new MyJobObject());`

Then in the view you could

`echo $job->getName();`

My problem is that Zend Studio can't perform autocomplete on `$job`, because it's type is unknown. Now there are PHPDoc tags that allow you to declare the type so that IDE's can perform autocomplete. The `@var` tag for example can be used in a class to define a property's type.

```
class MyJobObject
{
    /**
     * @var MyStatusObject
     */
    public $status;
}
```

**Is there a way to do something like this for local variables?**

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to use the one-line form: `/** @var $job MyJobObject */`

Note that some editors prefer the syntax the other way around: `/** @var MyJobObject $job */`

Comment: You can put this anywhere in an executable block and it will be effective until the end of the function (or any re-definition).

Comment: NetBeans seems to recognize `/* @var $varName varType */` syntax ( **note** there's just one `*` at the begining of comment)

Answer (score 43):

Both answers are wrong<sup>*</sup>, strictly speaking:

```
/** @var MyJobObject $job */
```

Is correct - the type is always the first argument, then you put a description or specify the variable itselfs.

Resources:

https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/tools/php/php-analyzer/guides/annotating_code
https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html

Otherweise, every modern PHP IDE is able to recognize almost any kind of comment syntax:

```
// @var
/* @var */
/** @var */
/* @var
*/
# @var
```

The most common, most readable and most widely accepted form is

```
/** @var <type> [variable [comment]] */


/** 
 * @var <type> [variable [comment]] 
 */
```

PSR-5 (Proposed) https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md

PSR-19 (Draft) https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc-tags.md

<sub>*) In 2013 the syntax might have been different.</sub>

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and also the only one supported by PHP CS fixer.

Comment: Agreed, immediately after entering in `/**` in PHPStorm above a variable it automatically goes to this syntax as well

Comment: @mvorisek but isn't the syntax for a [__class__ variable](https://docs.phpdoc.org/2.9/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) and not a local one?

Comment: @theking2 it is supposed to work for all VARiables. Their documentation might assume we don't use local variables in OOP programing.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud do on top of your view / template file.

```
<?PHP
/* @var $job MyJobObject */
?>
```

Comment: This is no longer the correct syntax. You now need an additional astrik in the comments punctuation as shown here `/** @var */`