# Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense gets errors which aren't

Tags: php, error-handling, symfony4

I'm working on a Symfony 4 project using Visual Studio Code with Intelephense.

Intelephense gets errors which aren't. There are some examples:

> Undefined method 'uasort'.

This error corresponding to this code:

```php
// Collection creation of seasons used in the periods 
$seasons = new ArrayCollection();
$sortedSeasons = new ArrayCollection();
    
//Search seasons used by periods
foreach ($advert->getPeriods() as $period) 
{
    $season = $period->getSeason();
    if (! $seasons->contains($season)) 
    {
        $seasons->add($season);
    }
}
    
// Sort seasons by ascending cost 
$iterator = $seasons->getIterator();
$iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->getCost() <=> $b->getCost();
});
```

An other example:

> Undefined method 'getAdvertMinPrice'.

```php
$minPrices = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Price::class)->getAdvertMinPrice($advert);
```

However, the method exists in the PriceRepository:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Repository\advert;

use App\Entity\advert\Price;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
    
/**
 * @method Price|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Price|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Price[]    findAll()
 * @method Price[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PriceRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Price::class);
    }
    
   /**
    * Get the minimum price from an advert
    *
    * @param [type] $advert
    * @return Price[]
    */ 
    public function getAdvertMinPrice($advert): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->andWhere('p.price = (
                            SELECT MIN(p2.price)
                            FROM ' . $this->_entityName . ' p2
                            WHERE p2.advert = :val
                        )'
                       )
            ->setParameter('val', $advert)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
        }
    }
```

There is the Price name space:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\advert;

use App\Entity\advert\Advert;
use App\Entity\advert\Period;
use App\Entity\backend\Season;
use App\Entity\backend\Duration;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\advert\PriceRepository")
 * 
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"duration", "season"},
 *     message="A price already exists for this season and this duration."
 * )
 */
class Price
{
```

And the use command in the file where I have the problem:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\advert;

use App\Entity\backend\VAT;
use App\Entity\advert\Price;
```

I don't understand where is the problem. I have searched for days without result.

Somebody would have an idea about this problem origin?

Comment: So, VSCode reports these errors, but your actual webserver doesn't?

Comment: @Jeto Indeed, errors only come from VSCode, not from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio Code extensions.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: I suppose because this is how he solved the problem and so left it up for anyone else having issues.

Answer (score 39):

Simply reloading the window (VSCode) often solves the problem. No need to reinstall the extension then.

To reload vscode open the command palette (`F1`) and select `Developer: Reload Window`. This is equal to restarting the editor.

Comment: Please state how and possibly why this fixes the issue.

Comment: How? Going to close vscode and open again the editor?

Comment: `F1` > `Developer: Reload Window` has the same effect as closing and opening again vscode

Comment: I have to restart VSCode every time I install a new package. Fun times.

Comment: Good answer, Thank you 
it solves a lot of problems with typing in symfony and other problems related to attributes in doctrine.

Comment: This worked for me - and is probably the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I have found a solution for this:

Here is some code from a project of mine:

```php
/** @var ActivityRepository */
$activityRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Activity::class);
return $this->json($activityRepo->search($searchData['text']));
```

My "->search" was giving me error,
then added the PHPDoc comment above my variable:

/** @var ActivityRepository */

and now it works!

Also check this out:

[How to declare the type for local variables using PHPDoc notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462390/how-to-declare-the-type-for-local-variables-using-phpdoc-notation)

Comment: This simple solution also works when you have something to do with Codeception / Stub::make(). I need to state @var \Models\MyClass $theClass before I use $theClass = Stub::make(MyClass::class, ....)

Answer (score 0):

The first error seems to be that `$iterator` is not an [ArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.uasort.php). You will need to check its type and if it's not `ArrayIterator` (or a `class` inherited from it), then that's the reason of the first error. On a subjective note, your situation seems to be some general problem with your dev environment.

Since `PriceRepository` has the method which your second error complains about, this seems to be the case that different `Price` and `PriceRepository` classes might be implemented in different namespaces and the wrong being in use. However, to determine whether this is true you will need to edit your question and provide the full definition of `PriceRepository`, Price and the use commands in the file where you have the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I added the asked code to my post.

Comment: @ChristopheDubois thank you. Can you also add class PriceRepository?

Comment: @ChristopheDubois no. You have a single line of it and from that we are unable to determine whether the right price is being in use.

Comment: I again formatted the post to better see the PriceRepository code. Do I must add anything else?

Comment: @ChristopheDubois no, now we can see that ```App\Repository\advert``` is the namespace in use. What happens if you execute compose install or compose update?

Comment: @Larjos Arpad Sorry, I didn't see your message. I executed composer update and I have this error :  Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\address\AddressRepository": argument "$registry" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry" instead.

Comment: @Larjos Arpad In each Repository, I changed Use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface; by use  use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry; and public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry) by public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry). I don't have anymore server errors but I always have the Intelephense error about the not existing getAdvertMinPrice function.