# Why is AbstractDashboardController missing in my Symfony 5 project

Tags: php, controller, bundle, symfony5, easyadmin3

I'm running a symfony 5.2 project. I choose to use EasyAdmin 3 for the Dashboard creation.

I followed [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html) and typed the following command:

```
 composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle
```

It created a DashboardController class which extends AbstractDashboardController.

Unfortunately this EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController does not exist.
VsCode doesn't find its definition and when i run my project i got a "service not found" error.

[image: See the code]

Does anybody have any idea of what's happening to me?
I looked on the internet but didn't found something relevant.
My composer is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with abstract dashboard and abstract controller, in case you are using VSCode, hope this helps you.

[Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense gets errors which aren't..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64980993/14380191)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you need to put Dashboard_ROUT() function

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution was quite simple ... i juste deleted the use AbstractDashboardController and re import it. I had to do this with few classes.

I can't explain why since i got the same error with a fresh install and had to do it again.