# How to quickly create editor fold?

Tags: intellij-idea, netbeans, ide

When I was editing GUI class I've found editor fold.

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
...
// </editor-fold>
```

I've started using it for my own purposes, but it's couple of words to write. So I'm looking for any faster way.

Comment: I was looking for the other values of default state.  Apparently ïf you leave the string empty: ""; that is 'expanded'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found it and it's simple :)

http://wiki.netbeans.org/SurroundWithCodeFolding

Answer (score 32):

In Netbeans, you can type 'fcom' and press 'TAB'.

More shortcuts [here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/top-10-interesting-netbeans-shortcuts)

Answer (score 20):

It is now the default behavior in Netbeans 7.3.1.

Just select the lines and click `Surround with ...` as below snapshoot.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The previous solutions didn't work for me (maybe because I'm on a mac) so here's how I did it:

1. Go to IntelliJ IDEA > **Preferences** > **Editor** > **Live templates**
2. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the top right, enter your template name and the following code:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="$DESCRIPTION$">
$SELECTION$$END$
// </editor-fold>
```

3. In the description tab, enter "**Code folding**", click "**Define**" (next to "No applicable context yet") and select "**Java**" (or you can be more specific if you want), check the "Reformat according to style" checkbox and click Ok
   Now, if you select multiple lines of text in the editor, press
    <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Windows) and select the "Code folding" template, enter a description and you're done.

Comment: The previous suggestions didn't work, because they were for a different IDE. Thanks for your instructions :)

Comment: In IDEA 2021 both `<editor-fold>` and `region..endregion` code folding styles seem to be available out of the box, no need for a custom template. Just open the Template menu and select.

Comment: note there is alternative code-folding syntax: `//region` + `//endregion`. But I still prefer `<editor-fold>`