# Counting duplicates in one array using another array fails to execute (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

Have 2 hours to finish my homework, and I'm stuck at this last method which to me seems to be correct, but the debugger fails to execute it.

In the method below (getPopularLine), I need to find a bus number(we call them line numbers in my country) which is the most "popular"(basically I need to return the lineNumber of a BusArrival object that appeared the most in the _buses array(duplicates)).

Just to make my question clearer, I'm using BlueJ and whenever I try to run the debugger, it just says "virtual machine is executing....." and it never does.Everything else is running fine, I'm not getting any errors, it says the syntax is fine.

This is the code I came up with :

```
public class BusStop
{
  private BusArrival[] _buses;
  private int _noOfBuses;
  final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;

  //================================ CONSTRUCTORS ============================//

    public BusStop(){
      _buses = new BusArrival[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
      _noOfBuses = 0;
     }


    public BusStop(int size){       
        _buses = new BusArrival[size];  
        _noOfBuses = 0;             
    }
  //=============================== METHODS =================================//
public int getPopularLine(){
    int[] busLine = new int[100];
    int popularLine = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= busLine.length; i++){ //bus numbers are between 1 and 99.
        for (int j = 0; j <_buses.length; i++){
            if(_buses[j] == null){
                continue;
            }
            if(i == _buses[j].getLineNum()){ //getLineNum() method returns the bus number of a bus(BusArrival object).
                busLine[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= busLine.length; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= busLine.length; j++){
            if(busLine[i] > busLine[j]){
                popularLine = i;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return popularLine;
}

public boolean add (int line, int pass, Time1 t){
    for (int i=0; i < _buses.length; i++){
        if(_buses[i] == null){
            _buses[i] = new BusArrival(line, pass, t);
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Here's my main method :

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main (String [] args){
      BusStop first = new BusStop(4);
      Time1 one = new Time1(10,30,0);
      Time1 two = new Time1(10,0,0);
      Time1 three = new Time1(9,40,0);
      first.add(1,2,two);
      first.add(1,4,two);
      first.add(2,4,three);
      System.out.println(first.getPopularLine());
    }
}
```

The following 2 constructors are probably irrelevant, but I'm posting them just for things to make sense.

Here is a constructor of a BusArrival class( :

```
public BusArrival(int lineNum, int pass, int h, int m, int s){

    _lineNumber = lineNum;
    _noOfPassengers = pass;
    _arrivalTime = new Time1(h, m, s);

}
```

And here's a constructor of the Time1 class :

```
public Time1(int h, int m, int s)
{

    _hour = h;
    _minute = m;
    _second = s;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well I'm using BlueJ and whenever I try to run it, it just says "virtual machine is executing....." and it never does.Everything else is running fine, but I'm not getting any errors, it says the syntax is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your first inner loop: it should be `j++` but you got `i++` (the lesson to learn here: give your variables descriptive names). That's why your program is hanging (for the future, you can step through it it the debugger to see what's going on).

Also, the way you count those duplicates is horrible. You don't need to do as many passes through `buses` as you have line numbers. Just go through the array once, and got each bus, get it's line number and increase the corresponding count. You don't need the outer loop, and you don't need the `if` statement.

Now your second loop is wrong. You should be comparing `busline[I]` with the `puoularLine`, and, again, you don't need the inner loop, can do it in one pass.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, it doesn't hang anymore :) but the busline[i] will give me only the value stored in the element i, which is the amount of duplicates, it will not give me the bus number.

Comment: @PainKiller and what does `i` indicate in that case?

Comment: @Painkiller you are correct, I misspoke. `popularLine` holds the bus number. You need another variable to keep the maximum number seen so far as you go through the array, and compare each next element to it.

Comment: kind of bad advice `i` and `j` are the de facto names for short lived loops

Answer (score 1):

There are some Java-conventions which deserve respect.

**Step One**

I have renamed your `Time1` class as `ArrivalTime` and removed variables/properties/parameters representing `seconds`, because Java loves realistic approach. I renamed your parameters and property-names as well, like "[Java-drinkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions)" usually do:

```
public class ArrivalTime {
    private final int hours;
    private final int minutes;

    public ArrivalTime(int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }
}
```

**Step Two**

I've done the same to your `BusArrival`-class

```
public class BusArrival {

    private final int lineNumber;
    private final int passengerCount;
    private final ArrivalTime arrivalTime;

    public BusArrival(int lineNumber, int passengerCount, int hours, int minutes) {
        this(lineNumber, passengerCount, new ArrivalTime(hours, minutes));
    }

    public BusArrival(int lineNumber, int passengerCount, ArrivalTime arrivalTime) {
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
        this.passengerCount = passengerCount;
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    public int getLineNumber() {
        return lineNumber;
    }
}
```

**Step Three**

I've almost totally changed your `BusStop` class.

- Try to use `<editor-fold>` instead of ugly long comments
  (especially for NetBeans; find more @ [How to quickly create editor fold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251770/how-to-quickly-create-editor-fold))
- `BusStop` class has a property `Map<Integer, Set<BusArrival>> busArrivals`, which means it becomes a kind-of Generic LinkedHashMap-enhancement, where `Integer`-keys represent line-number (bus-number), and to each key a collection (Generic `Set`) of unique `BusArrival`s is attached.
- As an enhancement to this "custom `LinkedHashMap`", I've replaced your `add` function with the one you need to add entries to the class.
- And I've used `Lambda` within your `getPopularLine()` function which makes the calculations faster, easier and is visually much richer. With the `reduce` method I "ask" Mr. Lambda to give me just one key (= lineNumber) from within my LinkedHashMap which points to most BusArrivals.
- with the private (WriteOnly) property `max` I prevent adding more buslines than predefined (not arrivals; if you need to prevent adding more arrivals than total count of BusArrivals, add the function `getTotalArrivals()` (see on the bottom of my post) into your `BusStop` class and replace `if (busArrivals.size() < max)` from within `add(BusArrival busArrival)` function by `if (getTotalArrivals() < max)`.

So,

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class BusStop {
    private final Map<Integer, Set<BusArrival>> busArrivals;
    private final int max;

    public BusStop(final int max) {
        busArrivals = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Set<BusArrival>> getBusArrivals() {
        return busArrivals;
    }

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Engine Enhancement">
    public int getPopularLine() {
        return busArrivals.keySet().stream().reduce(0, (previous, current)
                -> (busArrivals.keySet().contains(previous) && busArrivals.get(previous).size() > busArrivals.get(current).size())
                ? previous
                : current);
    }

    public boolean add(BusArrival busArrival) {
        if (busArrivals.size() < max) {
            Set<BusArrival> arrivals = busArrivals.get(busArrival.getLineNumber());
            if (arrivals == null) {
                arrivals = new LinkedHashSet<>();
            }
            arrivals.add(busArrival);
            busArrivals.put(busArrival.getLineNumber(), arrivals);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //</editor-fold>
}
```

**Step Four**

Of course, I've changed your `main` static function too:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BusStop first = new BusStop(4);
        first.add(new BusArrival(1, 2, new ArrivalTime(10, 30)));
        first.add(new BusArrival(1, 4, new ArrivalTime(10, 0)));
        first.add(new BusArrival(2, 4, new ArrivalTime(9, 40)));
        System.out.println(first.getPopularLine());
    }
}
```

**Extra method for `BusStop` class**

The `getTotalArrivals()` method:

```
public int getTotalArrivals() {
    return busArrivals.values().stream().mapToInt(value -> value.size()).reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

**And finally**

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this looks beautiful (sorry, saw this today), but unfortunately I couldn't change any classes/methods/parameters as they were all defined in my homework project and couldn't be changed, in this project I only had to write the BusStop class and all it's method, the other methods were given to me (last homework, I actually got a good grade), I could't use any of the stuff you mentioned simply because I don't even know how to use the stuff you wrote and even if I did I wouldn't be allowed to use it, as the professor says it all the time that advanced stuff is not allowed.