# How to make Visual Studio support code folding for if regions

Tags: visual-studio

I have a bunch of imbricated if in a code, how can I get code folding for if regions in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can automatically fold ifs in VS. Anyway, what about refactoring it in something simpler to read?

Comment: It's not my code, I just try to understand it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285422/visual-studio-c-sharp-statement-collapsing

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the programming language you use, [you can either specify regions (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx)

```
#region MyClass definition
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
    }
}
#endregion
```

or use the [(end)region pragmas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xkz944(v=vs.140).aspx) for C++ which are specific to Visual Studio.

```
// pragma_directives_region.cpp
#pragma region Region_1
void Test() {}
void Test2() {}
void Test3() {}
#pragma endregion Region_1

int main() {}
```